# Хранение даты и времени

Tags: android, sqlite

Подскажите, как лучше в sqlite хранить дату и время? Стоит ли использовать [DATE] или [TEXT]?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего хранить в INTEGER (на самом деле сохранять long) - время, взятое из `calendar.getTimeInMillis()`

Comment: а если хочу хранить форматированную дату типа [xx.xx.xxxx; xx:xx] ??

Comment: Загружаете миллисекунды а потом форматируете во что хотите. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
Хранить в текстовом формате наверно и по производительности удар, особенно если захотите делать выборки по дате.

Answer (score 0):

"Загружаете миллисекунды а потом форматируете во что хотите (SimpleDateFormat)." ... Не милисекунды, а секунды :))) Unix Date Time :))

1. Очень удобно при сравнении дат.
2. Мало памяти ( unsigned int требует 4 байта, а вот текст много :))

Comment: ну я коментировал пост который сохранял милисекунды, так что и грузить надо их же. в sqlite всеравно нету типа для этого, поэтому как интерпретировать сохраненное число все равно. 
В жаве тип Date хранит милисекунды, конструируется на основе их же, и текущее время просто получить в милисекундах. А насчет 4 байт, надо 8 т.к в жаве нет беззнаковых типов.

Comment: с этим я разобрался, еще не думал, но следующая проблема, наверно, будет - считывание времени с виджетов андроида, переводи его дня хранение и обратно - с БД на виджет